# Pow using rbenv, ruby

Tags: ruby, rbenv, rack-pow

I'am trying to use vagrant to start a [Hours](https://github.com/DefactoSoftware/Hours) dev environment

I have gotten everything to be setup whitout errors.
The thing is that when i try to access the server through POW i get this error.

```
    LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
~/Desktop/1dv032/ex1/hours/Hours/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I can't figure out why.

Ruby -v gives

```
2.3.1
```

Comment: If you're intending to use 2.3.1 then the problem here is you're not actually using it, that's a trace from the system Ruby 2.0.0. You'll need to check that whatever config for Hours is in place.

Comment: The system is telling me its running 2.3.1. The application itself requires it and the scripts won't run if its not 2.31. So i don't know how to track this down more.
It can't be that i messed something up on my own macOS? cause it worked before.

Comment: I know that's your intent but that stack trace is clearly 2.0.0. How are you launching Hours?

Comment: Whit the script that comes included. . bin/setup. then using foreman